# ckeditor display <p>Text</p> instead of displaying HTML

Tags: codeigniter, ckeditor

Ck-editor is not displaying my content as HTML instead it displaying with HTML tags.

I have initialize ck-editor by below code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   CKEDITOR.replace('long_description');
});
```

[image]

Comment: can you please show all options available in your editor? May be you just press ```source``` button of ckEditor.

Comment: No i don't press source button

Comment: This thing reproduce at my end when I tried type ```<p>Asd</p>```. otherwise not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check `form_helper` file. May be `html_escape` will be problematic. Please try by removing this `html_escape` and let me know if it works.